# Set custom expires in time expo-auth-session, for Fitbit API in react native, expo

Tags: javascript, react-native, oauth-2.0, expo, fitbit

###### I want to add custom expires time for fitbit implicit auth flow the default expires time is a day you can customize it I want to make it for a year. If you are using the web version you can change it by directly changing the expires_in params in the url.

###### As shown in this below url.

https://www.fitbit.com/oauth2/authorize?response_type=token&client_id=randomid&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fauth.expo.io%2F%40albert%2Fyourapp&scope=activity%20heartrate%20location%20nutrition%20profile%20settings%20sleep%20social%20weight%20oxygen_saturation%20respiratory_rate%20temperature&expires_in=31536000

```
WebBrowser.maybeCompleteAuthSession();

const useProxy = Platform.select({ web: false, default: true });
// Endpoint
const discovery = {
  authorizationEndpoint: 'https://www.fitbit.com/oauth2/authorize',
  tokenEndpoint: 'https://api.fitbit.com/oauth2/token',
  revocationEndpoint: 'https://api.fitbit.com/oauth2/revoke',
};

  const [request, response, promptAsync] = useAuthRequest(
    {
      responseType: ResponseType.Token,
      clientId: 'randomid',
      scopes: ['activity', 'profile'],
      redirectUri: makeRedirectUri({
        useProxy,
        scheme: 'nudge://',
      }),
    },
    discovery
  );

  const loginFitbit = async (token) => {
    if (token) {
      try {
        await signInFitbit(token, dispatch);
        await storeFitbitToken(token);
        setLoggedIn(true);
      } catch (e) {
        setLoggedIn(false);
        addError('Could not login Fitbit. Please try agian later.');
      }
    }
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (response?.type === 'success') {
      const { access_token } = response.params;
      console.log("res",response)
      loginFitbit(access_token);
    } else {
      console.log('error', response);
    }
  }, [response]);


  React.useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      let token;
      try {
        token = await getFitbitToken();
        setLoggedIn(true);
      } catch (e) {
        setLoggedIn(false);
        console.error(e);
      }
      dispatch({ type: 'RESTORE_FITBIT_TOKEN', token: token });
    };

    fetchData();
  }, [dispatch])
```

Answer (score 1):

If your application type is currently set to using the [Authorization Code Grant Flow](https://dev.fitbit.com/build/reference/web-api/developer-guide/authorization/), access tokens have a default expiration of 8 hours (28800 seconds). This cannot be changed.

However, if you'd like your users to be able to select how long your application can access their data, you will need to change your application settings to the Implicit Grant Flow. This authorization flow allows users to select how long they give consent to your application (1 day, 1 week, 30 days, or 1 year).

https://community.fitbit.com/t5/Web-API-Development/Query-parameter-expires-in-not-working/td-p/3522818

Comment: i am using implicit auth flow and i want to change the default expires in time i get for a day to a year for which a needed the syntax

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add extra query params for your auth request you need to add `extraParams` object with your custom fields.

https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/auth-session/#authrequestconfig

```
const [request, response, promptAsync] = useAuthRequest(
  {
    responseType: ResponseType.Token,
    clientId: "randomid",
    scopes: ["activity", "profile"],
    redirectUri: makeRedirectUri({
      useProxy,
      scheme: "nudge://",
    }),
    extraParams: {
      expires_in: 3600, // <--- new value
    },
  },
  discovery
);
```

Comment: i tried that but seems not to be working with the implicit auth flow i always get expires_in time for a day while in the web url version i can just edit the expires_in time in the query params to a year

Comment: its working thanks seems to be a problem with cache which i reset and now working!